# Set Row column to a gridView in a Windows store APP

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8.1

i created a GridView and all its rows are in the same color, i which i can modify these.

my code :

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.Items.Add("item 1 ");
gridView.Items.Add("item 2 ");
gridView.Items.Add("item 3 ");
```

they are all displayed in the gridview background color:

[image]

i want to change the GridView properties like color..., How can i proceed ?

i'm using C# and XAML.

Comment: why you are using GridView? LongListSelector would be best for your requirement

Comment: i'm not using windows phone app, i'm using windows 8 app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style specific items, declare an item template. -

```
<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridItemTemplate}" />
```

Then in your Pages Resources

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridItemTemplate">
    <Grid Background="#FF000000>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsText}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

To color the whole GridView -

```
<GridView Background="#FF000000" />
```

It's definitely recommended to do this through XAML declarations but if you have to do it through C# -

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.Items.Add("item 1 ");
gridView.Items.Add("item 2 ");
gridView.Items.Add("item 3 ");
gridView.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
```

Comment: i don't want the background of the grid view, i want the background of each item.

Comment: Then you use the ItemTemplate, as shown in the first section of the answer. If you wish it to be different for each GridViewItem then bind the background property to a value in your DataContext.